# How to sum two rows input file numbers to one row output file (PHP)

Tags: php

Input data:
In the input file INPUT.TXT there are two non-negative integers are given by two rows and the numbers are less than 10 powered by 100.

Output data:
in the OUTPUT.TXT  file is needed to return sum of the numbers to one row, without initial zeros

Example:

| # | input.txt | output.txt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 |
|  | 4 |  |

Comment: Looks like a student assignment.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you read the help pages yet? I especially recommend checking out 'How to ask a question' and referring to 'How to ask a homework question'. In short, we are not supposed to do your work for you. Please post, what you have tried before and tell us, what precise problem you have encountered.

Comment: To expand on my previous point, this is the article for you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: As a final hint, I suggest you look at the C-functions `fopen` and `fscanf`, which are available for both PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it , It will help you

```
$data = explode("\n", file_get_contents('INPUT.TXT'));
$sum = intval($data[0])+intval($data[1]);
echo $sum;
file_put_contents('OUTPUT.TXT', $sum);
```